# How to use Kubernetes service-annotations

Tags: kubernetes, jbossfuse, fabric8

How can we call a jboss fuse soap based webservice from another fuse soap service using kubernetes @endpoint @servicename annotations in fabric8 environment. Providing a example or reference is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to add an annotation, one does (from kubectl annotate -h):

> Update pod 'foo' with the annotation 'description' and the value 'my frontend'.
>   If the same annotation is set multiple times, only the last value will be applied
>   $ kubectl annotate pods foo description='my frontend'

But I *would not* use annotations to go directly to the endpoints. There are more standard ways to connect application tiers (environment variables and dns): http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/connecting-applications.html#accessing-the-service